# How to begin draw in one event and continue in another?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using Visual Studio 2013 to write a Windows Forms C# application. I want to draw game board on `Form1_Load` and draw pawns on button click. I have written two methods: `InitDraw()` and `Draw()`. When both method are in `Form1_Load()` or `button1_Click()` it's OK, but if `InitDraw()` is in `Form1_Load()` and `Draw()` is in `button1_Click()` - it draws only if I press Alt or move windows out of screen and move back to screen. I added `Invalidate()` but this does not help.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Bitmap drawBitmap;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InitDraw();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Draw();
        }

        private void InitDraw()
        {
            drawBitmap = new Bitmap(500, 500);
            pictureBox1.Image = drawBitmap;
        }

        private void Draw()
        {
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
            Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black);
            g.DrawLine(myPen, 0, 0, 100, 100);
            myPen.Dispose();
            g.Dispose();
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you call Draw() in Form1_Load()?

Comment: what about calling this.Refresh() ?

Comment: I am drawing on click because I wanna game board at start and two buttons like "Add pawn" and "Remove pawn". Refresh() helps.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody's stopping you from drawing wherever you want, the thing to remember is to do it on a bitmap image instead of trying to force it to screen. By this I mean you need to create your own `Bitmap` object, and any draw functions you call you call them on this.

To actually get this to show on screen, call the `Invalidate` function on the host control -- not a `PictureBox` by the way. Something lightweight like a panel will do. And in that control's `Paint` event simply draw your image.

You were sort of close, but you calling `Invalidate` on the form, besides the fact that it's horribly inefficient to redraw everything when you know exactly what needs to be redrawn, simply won't do anything. You don't rely on the `Paint` event, but on the intrinsic binding a `PictureBox` has with a `Bitmap` -- `Bitmap` who's handle you never change. As far as the `PictureBox` is concerned, everything is the same so it won't actually paint itself again. When you actually force it to paint itself by dragging the window outside the screen bounds and then back in it will read the bitmap and draw what you expect.

Comment: pictureBox1.Invalidate() instead of Invalidate() helps

Answer (score 0):

You must draw in the `Paint` event of the picture box. Windows might trigger the `Paint` event at any moment, e.g. if a window in front of it is removed or the form containing the picturebox is moved.

What you draw on the screen is volatile; therefore, let Windows decide when to (re-)draw. You can also trigger redrawing with

```
picturebox1.Invalidate();
```

or

```
picturebox1.Refresh();
```

Difference: `Invalidate` waits until the window is idle. `Refresh` draws immediately.

If you only draw in Form_Load or Button_Click, your drawing might get lost, when windows triggers a paint on its own. Try calling `picturebox1.Invalidate` in these events instead.